# php exec function not working for jar files

Tags: java, php, windows, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to execute a jar file from `php` in a windows environment. I want to send a string to a method in a jar file and get the output. Though i checked most of the posts related to this function still couldn't find the solution. Here is what i am executing.

```
<?php
$name="name";
$output = array();
exec('java -jar C:\Users\HP USER\Desktop\al\hel\out\artifacts\hel_jar\hel.jar', $output, $name);
print_r($output);
```

The output i am getting is `"Array ( )"`

Comment: are you sure the `.jar` file outputs something? Also do you get any errors from `exec`??

Comment: you can also try to execute a comand with redirection and just read the contents of the file. e.g `exec("java -jar my.jar > output.txt"); $result = file_get_contents("output.txt");`

Comment: What happens when you run that command as from the command line?

Comment: Capture stderr `2>&1` (or with a shell wrapper) to diagnose anything.

Comment: The jar files works fine in command line.It outputs a string value. But im getting only as  "Array()" when i run it in php. 
@NikosM. I tried ur code its also not outputting anything.

Comment: @mario i didnt get what 2>&1? and where to apply?

Comment: See the examples in the linked duplicate. Edit your question with further details once you've done so.

Comment: i tried all those.I have put this after trying all those methods.Still its not working

Comment: Edit your question with what you tried. And the resulting error message. If you don't have an error message, or a log, then nobody can help.